# How can I provide Google with better geolocation information for a local music site?

Tags: seo, geolocation

My site serves local music schedules based upon geolocation. The issue I'm running into is that when Google crawls the site, it usually does so from a limited number of IPs which when they trigger our geolocation feature, return results in the middle of Bakersfield (which may be sparse). Without trying to trick the Googlebot, I'd like to give Google a better idea of the geocentric results that we provide. Has anybody conquered this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible because google's IP's  will likely always come from the same area. You could however try to optimize for other search engines and see what they produce when they trigger your feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply structured data for your music events with the property **[MusicEvent](http://schema.org/MusicEvent)**. For geolocation, you can apply the element **location**. To clarify the localization, you can also apply information about the place of the event from outside sources, for example from ***Wikipedia*** and / or from **[The Getty Vocabularies](http://vocab.getty.edu/)**. For example:

```
<section vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="MusicEvent">
<h1 property=name>Symphony concert</h1>
<div property="location" typeof="MusicVenue">
<p property=description>Welcome to <span class=button property="name"><a class=button property="sameAs" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_Center">Chicago Symphony Center</a></span> ....</p>
<section property="address" typeof=PostalAddress>
<h2>Address</h2>
<p>The street address: <strong property=streetAddress>220 S. Michigan Ave</strong>.</p>
<p>The locality: <strong property=addressLocality>Chicago<link property="sameAs" href="http://vocab.getty.edu/tgn/7013596"></strong>.</p>
<p>The state/region: <strong property=addressRegion>Illinois<link property="sameAs" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illinois"></strong>.</p>
<p>USA<meta property=addressCountry content=US></p></section></div>
<time property="startDate" datetime="2017-05-23T20:00">May 23 at 20:00</time></section>
```

Check it out on the **[Google tester](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)**.

Comment: While this is something I do on the pages interior to the site (and thank you for the suggestion), it doesn't help my home page due to the fact that it will display events in the zip code where the requester's IP originates.

Comment: However, the zip code also has a way to localize the event.